# Is there a way to know which is the last token when iterating and parsing a JSON string in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm parsing some JSON data that I have on a string, to pass it to a file with a custom format. 
But I need to know which is the last token of the file, so that I close the tags with "}" instead of "}," (that would be, without the comma to have a correct syntax).

I tried to get the last token using the `Last` property, but it doesn't work as I thought.

This is the function I used to parse the data and write the file (it also prints the desired data to the terminal, but not in JSON data, that's why I'm parsing it first):

```
private static void ParseData()
        {
            JObject jsonData;

            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Globals.dataFile))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("{");

                    jsonData = JObject.Parse(Globals.json);
                    Console.WriteLine("*********************************************");
                    foreach (JToken tokens in jsonData["indicator"]["values"])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Fecha y hora: " + tokens["datetime"] + " Valor: " + tokens["value"] + Environment.NewLine + "*********************************************");
                        file.Write(Environment.NewLine + "\t{" + Environment.NewLine + "\t\t\"datetime\": " + tokens["datetime"] + ",");
                        file.WriteLine("\t\t\"value\": " + tokens["value"]);
                        if (tokens != tokens.Last)
                        {
                            file.WriteLine("\t},");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t},");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t}");
                        }
                    }

                    file.WriteLine("}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PrintExceptionMessage(ex);
            }
        }
```

And this is the format of the JSON file that I'm formatting:

```
{
    "indicator": {
        "name": "Precio medio horario final contratación libre suma de componentes",
        "short_name": "Precio medio horario final c.libre suma",
        "id": 10214,
        "composited": true,
        "step_type": "linear",
        "disaggregated": false,
        "magnitud": [{
                "name": "Precio",
                "id": 23
            }
        ],
        "tiempo": [{
                "name": "Hora",
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "geos": [{
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }
        ],
        "values_updated_at": "2019-01-31T08:05:32.000+01:00",
        "values": [{
                "value": 49.38,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T01:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T00:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 47.46,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T02:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T01:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T01:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 46.82,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T03:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T02:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T02:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 46.5,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T04:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T03:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T03:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 47.36,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T05:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T04:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T04:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 50.05,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T06:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T05:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T05:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 56.61,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T07:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T06:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T06:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 65.58,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T08:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T07:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T07:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 66.59,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T09:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T08:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T08:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 66.49,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T10:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T09:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T09:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 65.54,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T11:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T10:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T10:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 63.71,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T12:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T11:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T11:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 61.94,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T13:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T12:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T12:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 56.58,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T14:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T13:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T13:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }, {
                "value": 56.08,
                "datetime": "2019-01-31T15:00:00.000+01:00",
                "datetime_utc": "2019-01-31T14:00:00Z",
                "tz_time": "2019-01-31T14:00:00.000Z",
                "geo_id": 8741,
                "geo_name": "Península"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm only getting the "value" and "datetime" data from here.

The file I'm getting right now has this format (really bad one, I'm sorry):

```
{

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 01:00:00,        "value": 48,68
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 02:00:00,        "value": 45,7
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 03:00:00,        "value": 44,1
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 04:00:00,        "value": 44,53
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 05:00:00,        "value": 46,87
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 06:00:00,        "value": 49,84
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 07:00:00,        "value": 56,69
    },

    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 08:00:00,        "value": 62,5
    },
}
```

And what I'd like to get is:

```
{
    {
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 01:00:00,
        "value": 48,68
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 02:00:00,
        "value": 45,7
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 03:00:00,
        "value": 44,1
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 04:00:00,
        "value": 44,53
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 05:00:00,
        "value": 46,87
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 06:00:00,
        "value": 49,84
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 07:00:00,
        "value": 56,69
    },{
        "datetime": 01/02/2019 08:00:00,
        "value": 62,5
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot and I'm sorry. I'm really new to JSON and formatting it on C#.

Comment: So, it feels like your `ParseData` logic is to write JSON to `file`? If so, I would strongly suggest completely rethinking your approach. You should instead populate C# objects / arrays and then use `JsonConvert` to serialise that into a string to write to the file. Generating JSON by string concatenation is fraught with issues and complexities. You've run into one of them, but there are 50 of them hiding just around the corner... :)

Comment: @mjwills got it, I'll definetely do that from now on. I was breaking my head trying to format it that way... thank you so much!!

Comment: @BielSerrano, I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Comment: @er-mfahhgk I just tried it (sorry for being so late to answer) and it works perfectly, thank you a lot!!! :)

Comment: Glad to hear then please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your selected key/value pair from json into list of class object and then save it again to new file like

```
private static void ParseData()
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your input json file");

    JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(json);

    List<MyCustomClass> output = new List<MyCustomClass>();

    foreach (JToken tokens in jsonData["indicator"]["values"])
    {
        output.Add(new MyCustomClass { datetime = tokens["datetime"].ToString(), value = tokens["value"].ToString() });
    }

    File.WriteAllText(@"Path to your output json file", JToken.FromObject(output).ToString());
}
```

And you need a class object to parse your key/value pair,

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 05:30:00 AM",
    "value": "49.38"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 06:30:00 AM",
    "value": "47.46"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 07:30:00 AM",
    "value": "46.82"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 08:30:00 AM",
    "value": "46.5"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 09:30:00 AM",
    "value": "47.36"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 10:30:00 AM",
    "value": "50.05"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 11:30:00 AM",
    "value": "56.61"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 12:30:00 PM",
    "value": "65.58"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 01:30:00 PM",
    "value": "66.59"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 02:30:00 PM",
    "value": "66.49"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 03:30:00 PM",
    "value": "65.54"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 04:30:00 PM",
    "value": "63.71"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 05:30:00 PM",
    "value": "61.94"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 06:30:00 PM",
    "value": "56.58"
  },
  {
    "datetime": "31-01-2019 07:30:00 PM",
    "value": "56.08"
  }
]
```